# Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input? Not sure why

Tags: arrays, fortran, integer, gfortran

Below is the current program, everything checks out to me, except when I execute the program itself it gives me this error.

```
Fortran runtime error: Bad integer for item 1 in list input.
```

The first number is 60000.

```
    implicit none
    
    !declaring the single precision for real numbers, array, and variables.
    integer :: i, firstnumber
    real*4 :: average, sum_, standarddeviation
    
    real*4, allocatable :: arrayone(:)!making sure that the array is single precision real
    
    open(unit=1,file="C:\cygwin64\data sets for labs and assignments\Numbers.txt")!opening file
    
    do 
        read(1,*)firstnumber!reading the first number
    end do

    allocate(arrayone(firstnumber))!allocating the array with the first number variable obtained from previous statement
    
    close(1)
    
    do i = 2, firstnumber
    
    open(i,file="C:\cygwin64\data sets for labs and assignments\Numbers.txt")
        read(i,*)
        
        sum_ = Sum(arrayone) !sums all of the numbers from arrayone
        
        average = Sum_/firstnumber 
        
        standarddeviation = sqrt(sum_ - average) * (sum_ - average)!calculates the standard deviation of the data set
        
        close(i)
    end do
    print*,"Average = "
    print*,"Standard Deviation = "
    
    deallocate(arrayone)!Deallocating arrayone
    
    
    print*,"Done!"
    
    end program Assignmentthree
```

Comment: It seems you are learning as a Fortran beginner. Be advised that `real*4` is not a standard Fortran syntax, but a common non-standard extension. You should also make some own effort for debugging. Try to always print what you just read and diagnose what happens from that.

Comment: You try to read the `firstnumber` a large number of times, not once, because it's in a indefinite loop. That can't be what you mean? And with `read(i,*)` later you aren't reading in to any variable. Finally, opening the same file in different units is not the same as reading subsequent lines.

Comment: @VladimirF we have not learned how to debug a program, but the professor specifically asked that we use real*4; however, how does this relate to my question?

Comment: @francescalus So you are saying that I am trying to use firstnumber to much and how does that make the first integer in the open file, 60000, a "bad integer"? Also, if I state that i=2 before the do loop it should be able to read in subsequent lines?

Comment: Sorry to everyone, I am new to fortran.

Comment: You read it once and that's fine. Then you read the _next line_ which is the start of your real numbers, but are still in that loop reading in to `firstnumber` again. That's not fine.

Comment: So just to be clear, the first use in the first do loop is ok, but using it as a endpoint in the second do loop is not good?

Comment: @francescalus Update: I tried to use 60000 specifically but to no avail that was not the issue to the "Bad integer at unit 1 in list". I am really stuck as to how this 60000 number is a bad integer.

Comment: `60000` is not a bad integer, but you aren't reading `60000` the second time in the loop: remove that first `do`. You still won't have this program work (there are many other problems) but that first unnecessary loop is the (likely) cause of the first problem you see.

Comment: How does `real*4` being non-standard relate to your question? It doesn't. It was a friendly unsolicited advice to a beginner that the syntax is non-standard. If it is required by your instructor, you will have to use it anyway.

Comment: Your instructor did not teach you how to debug? You will have to learn some most-basic techniques yourself - or with our help. Exactly as I wrote: Insert some `print` statements into your code so that you know what the program is doing. Let the program tell you what it has just read each time.

Comment: Yea we have not gotten to the debugging section of the course, but thank you all so much, I will apply all this information to the program. Hopefully I can get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on francescalus' and Vladimir F's comments:

### Catching bugs

The simplest way of debugging a program is adding a bunch of `print` statements. If you add these to your code, like

```
    implicit none
    
    !declaring the single precision for real numbers, array, and variables.
    integer :: i, firstnumber
    real*4 :: average, sum_, standarddeviation
    
    real*4, allocatable :: arrayone(:)!making sure that the array is single precision real
    
    open(unit=1,file="C:\cygwin64\data sets for labs and assignments\Numbers.txt")!opening file
    
    do 
        read(1,*)firstnumber!reading the first number
        print *, 'firstnumber = ', firstnumber
    end do

    allocate(arrayone(firstnumber))!allocating the array with the first number variable obtained from previous statement
    
    close(1)
    
    do i = 2, firstnumber
    
    open(i,file="C:\cygwin64\data sets for labs and assignments\Numbers.txt")
        read(i,*)
        
        print *, 'arrayone = ', arrayone
        
        sum_ = Sum(arrayone) !sums all of the numbers from arrayone
        
        print *, 'sum_= ', sum_
        
        average = Sum_/firstnumber 
        
        print *, 'average= ', average
        
        standarddeviation = sqrt(sum_ - average) * (sum_ - average)!calculates the standard deviation of the data set
        
        print *, 'standarddeviation= ', standarddeviation
        
        close(i)
    end do
    print*,"Average = "
    print*,"Standard Deviation = "
```

then you can see what your program is actually doing, and work out what's going wrong.

### Your current error

Your first problem is that the lines

```
do 
  read(1,*)firstnumber!reading the first number
end do
```

are performing the `read` operation multiple times. It will literally try to read integers from the file forever. Obviously the file is finite, so eventually it runs out of valid things to read, and throws the error you are seeing.

To fix this, you should simply get rid of the infinite loop, by removing the lines `do` and `end do`.

### The empty read

Your next problem is the statement

```
read(i,*)
```

This reads from the file you just opened, but doesn't store the results anywhere. It looks like you're trying to populate the `arrayone` array, which you would do like

```
read(i,*) arrayone(j)
```

where `j` is the index of `arrayone` corresponding to the element which you want to fill.

### In a loop

The other problem you have is that you're doing a lot of things inside a loop which you should be doing outside the loop. As it stands, the code

```
do i = 2, firstnumber
  open(i,file="C:\cygwin64\data sets for labs and assignments\Numbers.txt")
  read(i,*)
  sum_ = Sum(arrayone)
  average = Sum_/firstnumber 
  standarddeviation = sqrt(sum_ - average) * (sum_ - average)
  close(i)
end do
```

will:

- open the file
- read the first number in the file, but not store it anywhere
- calculate the sum, average and standard deviation of the entire array `arrayone`, even though most of the elements of `arrayone` are not yet filled.
- close the file

and it will do all of this over and over again, `firstnumber` times.

I suspect that what you want to do is read the `firstnumber` elements of `arrayone` from lines `2` through `firstnumber+1` of the file, and only then (after the loop) calculate the sum, average, and standard deviation of `arrayone`.

In order to read multiple rows from your file, you should only open it once (at the statement `open(unit=1...`), and only close it once (using `close(1)`, but at the end of your program). Each `read` statement should then read from the same file (so each should be `read(1,...`).